# Expiration not specified" according to Gtmetrix

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp

I have a website https://royzez.com,I am using .htaccess to Leverage browser caching as mentioned code in  GT Metrix but still i am getting the message  (expiration not specified). These Images are coming from CDN. So there is some other configuration in CDN server? How to fix this issue.
The code i am using is `

```
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 1 month"
```

# CSS
    ExpiresByType text/css                              "access plus 1 month"

# Favicon (cannot be renamed!) and cursor images
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon                          "access plus 1 week"

# HTML
    ExpiresByType text/html                             "access plus 0 seconds"

# JavaScript
    ExpiresByType application/javascript                "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript              "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript                       "access plus 1 year"

# Manifest files
    ExpiresByType application/manifest+json             "access plus 1 year"

```
ExpiresByType application/x-web-app-manifest+json   "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest                   "access plus 0 seconds"
```

# Media files
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/bmp                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg                            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml                         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/webp                            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/webm                            "access plus 1 month"

# Web fonts

```
# Embedded OpenType (EOT)
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject         "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType font/eot                              "access plus 1 month"

# OpenType
ExpiresByType font/opentype                         "access plus 1 month"

# TrueType
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf                "access plus 1 month"

# Web Open Font Format (WOFF) 1.0
ExpiresByType application/font-woff                 "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff               "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType font/woff                             "access plus 1 month"

# Web Open Font Format (WOFF) 2.0
ExpiresByType application/font-woff2                "access plus 1 month"

# Other
ExpiresByType text/x-cross-domain-policy            "access plus 1 week"
```

`

Please help me with this problem I searched everything in internet I am not getting solution. Thank you so much  and sorry for the bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Cache Policy seems good here: 
https://www.dareboost.com/en/report/55b8bd890cf21c478235ce22

Where was the test location you ran your test from?